# SQL Conversion error when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Query from yesterday date from 5pm

```
Declare @DATEFROM DATETIME=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()-1,103) + '17:00:00.00'
select @DATEFROM
```

Expecting 2018-02-05 17:00:00

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

SQL Server 2008. Need format yyyy-mm-dd (2018-02-05 17:22:00.000)

Comment: Have you Googled how to create date and time in SQL Server????  I bet there are tons of example.

Comment: This  has worked before..

Comment: Missing a space before the 17:00. Should be ' 17:00:00.000'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy implementation:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 17, GETDATE()-1 - CAST(getDate() as time))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a date string, use `dateadd`:

```
Declare @DATEFROM DATETIME=dateadd(hh,17,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()-1,103))
select @DATEFROM
```

Or if you must add a date string, cast it into a datetime first:

```
Declare @DATEFROM DATETIME=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()-1,103) + cast('17:00:00.00' as datetime)
select @DATEFROM
```

Comment: 2018-05-02 17:00:00.000 bringing back no data. Need format 2018-02-05 17:00:00.000'

Comment: I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get varchar first and then cast back to datetime

```
Declare @DATEFROM varchar(22) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()-1,103) + ' 17:00:00.00'
select CAST(@DATEFROM AS datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, however this will produce the date with the time index you are looking for, unless specifically you're looking for yesterday's date in which you can replace the first 0 with 1

```
declare @date datetime = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, sysdatetime()), 0) + .70833333333333333333
select @date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @dateFrom datetime=cast(dateAdd(dd, - 1,cast(getDate() as date) ) as datetime) +'17:00:00'
```

Comment: Please elaborate rather than just posting code. It will help the user understand what you are doing and why.